# How to update the JSON output of nestable manually

Tags: jquery, json

I am creating a JSON by adding multiple answers to a question. I am using nestable to rearrange the items. But problem is the JSON output is formed only when i am rearranging them, I want to create the output when adding new answer.

Follwing is the code for JSON output.

```
var updateOutput = function(e)
{
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

$('#nestable_1').nestable().on('change', updateOutput);

updateOutput($('#nestable_1').data('output', $('#nestable_1_op')));
```

I want the update the JSON output by a onclick method or any similar method.

Answer (score 1):

just execute updateOutput($('#nestable_1').data('output', $('#nestable_1_op')));